# Best way to rearrange an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list

What is the best way to rearrange elements in an list? I need the ability to move elements to move elements in the list, one step back or forward in the index. I was thinking of getting the index of the item, adding it at index -1 / +2 and removing the old reference.

Is there a faster way to handle rearranging without creating duplicates in the list in the process.

Comment: Please provide an example. For example, having the list ABCDEF, what do you want? Something like ABCEDF (moving an element) or ABCEF (removing an element)? Why do you write -1 / +2 instead of -1 / +1?

Comment: I had +2 as if you add say 'C' in your example to indexof(c)+1, you'll get ABCCDEF removing the old C will take it back to ABCDEF. putting +2 will give you ABCDCEF and removing old value will give ABDCEF. Thus +2 instead of +1. But Collections.swap was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Use the JDK's swap method**

The JDK's Collections class contains a method just for this purpose called [Collections.swap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29). According to the API documentation this method allows you to "swap the elements at the specified positions in the specified list."

I suggest this solution so that you don't have to remove elements from the List and so that you don't have to roll your own swap method. Also, it looks like this method has been around since the 1.4 release of Java so it should work for most of the modern JDKs.

Comment: I only remembered it because I was looking at it today for my project. It is in one of the dark corners of the JDK.

Comment: Very cool, I don't think I've ever used that method either, but it definitely could come in handy.