# Java (Android) re-ordering an object list

Tags: java, android, list

I read the documentation on this, and I'm not totally clear.  I've zeroed in on the set method and I'm thinking that I would do reordering like this:

```
list.set(0,myObj);//Move first
list.set(list.indexOf(myObj) - 1, myObj);//Move up
list.set(list.indexOf(myObj) + 1, myObj);//Move down
list.set(list.size() - 1, myObj);//Move last
```

The documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html states that set returns the object that is displaced.  So that leads me to think that I then have to re-place that object.  Am I correct?  So after a set operation as I described I would have two references to the object in the list.  This would mean I'd have to loop down the list to place all the other object appropriately?

Comment: No set actually moves the object for you. I believe it returns the object also for error checking.

Comment: so are you saying, set is what I want?  and it will move everything else below the object appropriately?

Comment: Use `Collection.rotate()`. As I mentioned ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Collections](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html) class to make things like reverse, reorder, sort etc.
You're looking probably for [rotate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List%3C?%3E,%20int%29) or [swap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List%3C?%3E,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 5):

Use [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class's `swap()` for it

```
swap(List list, int i, int j)
```

Swaps the elements at the specified positions in the specified list.

**Example:**

```
Collections.swap(arrayList,0,4);
```

Comment: OK, that's looking promising for moving up and down one at a time, but what if I want to move first?  I guess just use a loop to move it to the top

Comment: OK, thanks, I think that's what I will do.  I'm going to accept pawelzieba's answer since he mentioned collections first and he has way less reputation.  Thank you :-)

Comment: Thanks, so I vote up for user370305, he first wrote about `swap`

Answer (score 2):

Sound like you want to insert an object at the top o' the list.
Don't use set.

Use [List.add(0, myObj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

It will bump the rest down.

Comment: No, the object is already in the list.  I want to change it's order.

Comment: I want to move to first, move up by one, move down by one, and move to last.

Comment: ah, sorry.  I didn't realize it was already a member o' the list.

Comment: This question has a good answer (Collections.swap): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657581/best-way-to-rearrange-an-arraylist-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the element is replaced. It is easily fixed though:

```
int index = list.indexOf(myObj);
list.set(index, list.set(index - 1, myObj)); //Move up
```

This will switch `list(index - 1)` with `list(index)`. The other operations can be implemented in the same way.

Comment: That looks like it would work as well.  I'm gonna use Collections.swap I think it would be more readable.  Thank you! :-)